# Filter an array of objects with latest date if array contains same date with different timestamp in multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, filter

I have an array of objects and each object has the date. I need to filter the array and get the objects that contains latest date.

```
[
  {
    "Id": 25,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T00:01:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 26,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T11:10:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 27,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T16:12:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 30,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-27T00:08:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 31,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-27T10:20:10.001Z"
  }
         
]
```

After filtering the array I need the array should look like below

```
[
  {
    "Id": 27,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T16:12:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 31,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-27T10:20:10.001Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to try to do it then get help if it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to use the reduce but that only returns the latest date. Here is the code I tried ```result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.MeasureDate > b.MeasureDate ? a : b); ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You say you need to get the object that contains the latest date but the example you give has two different dates. What exactly is the rule you need to apply?

Comment: @Raj Isn't the latest date what you want? Your question says you want the object with the latest date. Your expected results do not show this though. Your expected results show two objects with different dates. Id 31 is later that id 27

Comment: @DavePile, I want all the objects in the list that has unique dates with latest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dateItems = [
  {
    "Id": 25,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T00:01:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 26,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T11:10:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 27,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-26T16:12:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 30,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-27T00:08:01.001Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": 31,
    "MeasureDate": "2022-08-27T10:20:10.001Z"
  }
         
];

// As we loop through your dateItems array we need to keep track of the Latest DateTime for each day
// Probably the easiest way is to create a key on a property for each date and then attach the object
// from your array to that key if it is the first for that date or later than an existing one.
const latestDateTimesByDate = {};

dateItems.forEach( di => {

  // Use the date part of the date time as a key/ property name on the latestDateTimesByDate object
  let dateKey = di.MeasureDate.substring(0, 10);
  
  // If that date key doesnt exist or the current MeasureDate  is gretaer than the recorded one
  if( !latestDateTimesByDate[dateKey] || di.MeasureDate > latestDateTimesByDate[dateKey].MeasureDate) {
    latestDateTimesByDate[dateKey] = di;
  }

});

// if you need it as an array then add each of the date properties to an element of an array
const finalArray = [];
Object.keys(latestDateTimesByDate).forEach( key => finalArray.push(latestDateTimesByDate[key]));
```

Comment: thanks for providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your probleme :

```js
function similarDates(obj){ 
    date_obj = new Date(obj.MeasureDate);
    // Getting only the dates with same year, month, day
    let sim_dates = popo.filter((objs) => {
        date =  new Date(objs.MeasureDate)
        return date.toDateString() === date_obj.toDateString()
    });
    // Returning the similare dates
    return sim_dates
}
```

```js
function filterData(array) {
    result = []

    while(array.length) {
        console.log(array)
        var sameElement =  similarDates(array[0]);

        // removing all the treated elements from the array
        array = array.filter( ( el ) => !sameElement.includes(el));
    
        result.push(sameElement.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.MeasureDate) - new Date(a.MeasureDate)).shift());
    }

    return result;
}
```